# How to submit form data in ajax using enter in the keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am creating a comment functionality and below are my code so far.

**html**

```
<form action="http://website.com/transaction_items/add_comment" class="" id="form-comment" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="checklists_item_id" value="6" style="display:none;"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1" style="display:none;"> 
  <div class="input-group col-xs-12"> 
    <input type="text" name="comment" value="" class="form-control" id="comment-input" placeholder="Enter your comments.."> 
    <span class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button class="btn btn-default" id="doc-comment" type="button">Post</button> 
    </span> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

**jQuery**

This function is called when document is ready.

```
function comment () {
  $('#doc-comment').click(function (e) {
    var form_id    = '#' + $(this).parents('form').attr('id');

    // submit data from the form
    submit.send(form_id);
  });
}
```

The problem:

Using the button `<button class="btn btn-default" id="doc-comment" type="button">Post</button>` to submit data work fine, but 
if I use enter in the keyboard, submit.send(form_id);  will not do its function, instead the default form submission will execute.

How can I use ajax if use enter in the keyboard to submit form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nutshell

```
$("#form-comment").on('submit', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //  do your ajax stuff here
});
```

you can then toss the onclick button listener.. as this will handle the button submit as well

Comment: good idea, but still not working, I'm also using codeigniter, but I think its not about codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to submit a form then simply pressing the `submit` button.

You need to:

- Use the forms `submit` method
- Keep the form from doing the full submit.

-

```
// This will catch the *enter* as well as the submit button
$("#form-comment").on('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // You can then submit the form via ajax and update things as needed.
});
```

IF you are going to use a `button` you should at least do a

```
<button type="button">...</button>
```

which behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form-comment").keyup(function (e) {               // On pressing enter 
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     // put your ajax code here
            }
 });
```

You may have to disable the default Enter event for the form submit button as  well depending on your browser.

So in the Jquery Button click function  make sure you have something like

```
  event.preventDefault();
```